# Scroll page with mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have placed two buttons in my page. When you click on them the page scrolls down/up and it works fine. I tried to replace the event `click` with the `mousedown` event in order to scroll the page during mousedown event but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-down', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 300
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-up', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 300
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

What am I missing here?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-down', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 10
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('mousedown', 'a.scroll-up', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 10
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.scroll-down {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0.2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 2.75rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(90, 92, 105, 0.5);
  line-height: 46px;
}

.scroll-down:focus,
.scroll-down:hover {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-down:hover {
  background: #5a5c69;
}

.scroll-down i {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.scroll-up {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0.2rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  width: 2.75rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(90, 92, 105, 0.5);
  line-height: 46px;
}

.scroll-up:focus,
.scroll-up:hover {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-up:hover {
  background: #5a5c69;
}

.scroll-up i {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="scroll-up rounded" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="scroll-down rounded" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems you need to queue the clicks or mousedowns

Comment: `mousedown` fires _once_ when you press the button down, it won't keep on firing while you keep the button pressed.

Comment: The page seems to scroll a bit, please define "_it doesn't work_".

Comment: There's no "adding up of animations" - there's only 1.  Add a `console.log("mousedown")` before the animation.  The issue appears to be related to it being an `a` - change to a `button type='button'` and the "scroll to top when you hold it down" doesn't happen.   I don't know why. Reproduction:  run in a small window, scroll to bottom, "click" up, moves a little bit, hold mouse down for only slightly longer than a "click" that would not be enough to scroll all the way to the top: always jumps to the top.  Change to a `button` and it doesn't do the same.

Comment: Adding `$(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-up', () => { return false; });` will stop the always-scroll-to-top, so looks like it's reloading the page (not scrolling) on "click".  Hard (just for me?) to tell in the snippet.

Comment: "*in order to scroll the page during mousedown event"* as noted above, there's only 1 "mousedown" event - one option might be to start moving on `mousedown` and then stop moving on `mouseup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseup event because when user presses the mouse button it will be fired then mousedown event fired. The mousedown event working but due to fired after mouseup event, its timing, scroll position or ratio and window size have to use for scrolling speedily.

I have tried with mousedown event using your code it works but scroll little bit due to low elapsed time, scroll position or ratio and window size.

In my opinion, better to use mouseup

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', 'a.scroll-down', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 300
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('mouseup', 'a.scroll-up', function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 300
  }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.scroll-down {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0.2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 2.75rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(90, 92, 105, 0.5);
  line-height: 46px;
}

.scroll-down:focus,
.scroll-down:hover {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-down:hover {
  background: #5a5c69;
}

.scroll-down i {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.scroll-up {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0.2rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  width: 2.75rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(90, 92, 105, 0.5);
  line-height: 46px;
}

.scroll-up:focus,
.scroll-up:hover {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-up:hover {
  background: #5a5c69;
}

.scroll-up i {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Mouse</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">mybutton</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="scroll-up rounded" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="scroll-down rounded" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*Use mousup event*" is just wrong because then you can't "watch" it scroll up and stop at the point you want.   You hold down the mouse for x seconds *while nothing happens* then let go and *then* it scrolls.  Not a good UX.

Comment: hold on mouse in case of mousdown, not for mouseup. I try it but I will again try if still anything wrong